# IP Address Class GetAddressBytes method putting octets in odd indices of the byte array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program that stores ip addresses inside a hash table utilizing the IP Address class that is built into C#. I start by using a textbox for the user to input the IP address into. My code then takes the text from the textbox, places it into a string variable, and then uses the IPAddress.Parse method to verify/store it in the IP Address data type.

```
// Variables
IPAddress address;
string userEntry;

// Grab the IP, verify it, and convert it to the IP Address data type
userEntry = textBox1.Text;
address = IPAddress.Parse(userEntry);
```

I then have function that takes the IP Address (by way of the IP Address data type) and converts it into an array of bytes using the GetAddressBytes method. Following this, I use a for loop to cycle through the byte array and multiply the value of each index by 256 to the power of the place of place of the octet being looked at in descending order (i.e. the first octet looked at is multiplied by 256^3, the second by 256^2 etc...). I do this so that I can have a unique number for each IP address (converting the IP address to its integer form) that I will be able to feed into my hashing algorithm.

```
        private UInt32 ConvertIP(IPAddress address) {
        byte[] bytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
        int counter = 3;
        uint answer = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) {

            MessageBox.Show(bytes[i].ToString());

            answer = answer + Convert.ToUInt32(bytes[i] * Math.Pow(256, counter));

            counter--;

        }

        return answer;
    }
```

I originally thought that this would work out quite well until I found out that I can enter partial IP addresses such as 255, 255.255, and 255.255.255. When using a break point to watch the different octets get added to the byte array, the octets seem to be added to the byte array in an odd order. When you just enter 255 the octet gets added to the 3rd spot in the array (fourth in reality, but labeled 3 because the array starts at zero), however, when you enter 255.255 the octets get placed in the 3rd spot and the 0 spot of the byte array and not in the 3rd and 2nd spots of the array as I would think. A picture of this is included below.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why the octets are being placed in the the byte array in such an odd order? Is it something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is called out in the documentation

> A one part address is stored directly in the network address. A two part address, convenient for specifying a class A address, puts the leading part in the first byte and the trailing part in the right-most three bytes of the network address. A three part address, convenient for specifying a class B address, puts the first part in the first byte, the second part in the second byte, and the final part in the right-most two bytes of the network address. For example:

When entering less than 4 parts for a dot notation address it interprets it as a class A, B or C address (depending on the number of parts entered)

Comment: Thank you very much, would you mind linking me to this part of the documentation? Also, do you know of any way to circumvent this short of error trapping to ensure that the user enters 4 octets on their own?